# How to write a C program for a computer without an Operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, system

Let us suppose that my computer does not have any operating system.
Is it possible to write a C program for running on this computer?
I think that it is possible to do that, but I'm not sure.
If this is possible, how can we do that?

Comment: Yes, first you must write a boot loader in assembly, and from the boot loader load compiled C code. If you follow this guide, you can do exactly that. https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial Instead of writing a kernel and an operating system of course, you'd just boot into your program.

Comment: Write a bootstrap loader on a different machine, cross compile and blow the PROM.  Plug it in and boot up.  That is what we used to do.

Comment: What is the computer? If the computer's firmware is UEFI you can just write a UEFI application in pure C (without a single line of assembly language).

Answer (score 1):

This is why the standard defines "freestanding" implementations.  Such implementations may be used to target hardware without any sort of OS or much of any support, really.  You would need an implementation that supported your particular hardware enviorment (whether that is an embedded system of some kind, or some other bare-bones hardware).  With that in mind, there are several important things to understand about freestanding implementations:

- The way that program/system startup and termination happens is completely implementation defined.  The might be a `main` that is called with some implementation-specific arguments, or there might be some other entry point(s) defined.  Termination may not even be possible.
- The standard library might be partly or even mostly missing -- there are only a few header files that a freestanding implementaion must support to be conforming (things like stdarg.h stdint.h, stdboolh. limits.h), so there might be no standard way of doing I/O or managing memory, for example.